# Java Executors cancel job by timeout with inner executor

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a big thread pool like

```
ThreadPoolExecutor pool = new ThreadPoolExecutor(cores, 50, 30L, TimeUnit.SECONDS, new ArrayBlockingQueue<>(3000));
```

I want to submit a task there. But I don't want to call future.get() at all, I want to submit it and forget.

But, I want my task to be cancelled in a certain time period. So I do the following:

```
public void run(){

FutureTask<WorkerWrapper> task = new FutureTask<>(()->worker.process(tmpArg));
executor.execute(task);
res=task.get(2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
executor.shutdown();    

}
```

In other words, I call executor inside executor. Is it safe and stable? Or can I cancel my task by timeout other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only real way to achieve this, AFAIK, is to have a second [ScheduledExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/j2se/j2se/1.5.0/jcp/beta1/apidiffs/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutor.html). You'd still need a handle of the `Future` but only pass it to the scheduled executor for cancellation.

```
Future<WorkedWrapper> task = executor.execute(() -> worker.process(tmpArg));
scheduledExecutor.schedule(() -> task.cancel(true), 2, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

There may be a more fluent way of handling this with `CompleteableFuture`s but I am not 100% sure of that.

Answer (score 0):

ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor has a method that allows to to schedule a runnable and get a future back. You can combine this with the timed get on the future:

```
ScheduedThreadPoolExecutor e = ...
Future<T> f = e.submit(new Runnable(){..},new T(){});
Object ignore = f.get(timeout, timeunit);
```